# Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal error

Tags: c

I am trying to get each word from the array and assign it to the variable word.

I am getting the error:

```
array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
```

My code:

```
int main() {
    
    static const char *list[8] = {
        "AHFDdgDsdfs", "QYUTTRREE", "PYRTRTTRY", "OPDDDaU",
        "HJFGHFDGD", "ADADADAS", "LPPPDDLSD", "KFDRKGDSGC"
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        char word[] = list[i];
        printf("Word: %s\n", word);
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why I am getting this error?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, but `const char *word = list[i];` is accepted by the compiler. I guess you intended to print `word` not `list[i]`.

Comment: how do you mean its unclear? I am trying to assign each word in the list to the variable name `word`

Comment: It's unclear, because it's a syntax error and you don't even use `word`. So there is no "use case".

Comment: I get the same exact error (just changed my question btw). I can't do `const` as its not a `const` since the value being assigned is always different.

Comment: There is a compiler warning for `char *word = list[i];` but not for `const char *word = list[i];`

Comment: cheers got you now

Answer (score 2):

You have a type mismatch, which is what gives you the compiler error:

```
const char *list[8]
```

This line declares `list` to be an array of size 8 of type "pointer to char", which means it stores 8 pointers.

This line:

```
char word[] = list[i];
```

declares `word` to be an array of `char` (of unknown size), and then tries to assign one of the pointers from `list` to it.

Though arrays and pointers are closely related in C, they are still not the same thing, so you can not assign a pointer to an array.

If you want to assign one of the pointers in `list` to the variable `word` you must declare it to be of the same type as elements in `list`:

```
const char *word = list[i];
```

Note that you can drop the `const` part and get a warning, since you will be turning a constant pointer to a non constant one, but the idea of "constants" is there to help the programmer and not really a limitation of the computer, so the compiler will usually let you get away with dropping it.

But that is a bad programming practice and should be avoided!